# Spring initiliser available java versions

Tags: spring-boot

Does Spring initialiser no longer support java version 8 as when I want to create an application I only get the option for java 17 and 21 and we currently have to use java 8 at my workplace and what is the alternative to using spring initialiser so that I can choose the version of java that I want to use.

I tried using IntelliJ to create my project but it's also not giving me the option to choose java 8  but only giving me 17 and 21. I also tried using the cli to create the project but it also gives me an error that it requires java 17 to be installed and I have java 8 installed on my PC.

Comment: It doesnt as Spring Boot 3 is the only supported version as of now. Spring Boot 3 requires Java 17 as a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Spring Boot 2.X is not supported anymore and it was the last version of Spring Boot that supported Java 8. Starting with Spring Boot 3.X, Java 17 or newer is required, as mentioned in the official release notes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki#release-notes

If you need to work with Java 8, you can set up your project manually or use Spring Initializr and then change the Spring Boot and Java versions manually.

As of today (December 5, 2023) the latest version of Spring Boot still supporting Java 8 is `2.7.18`. You can find the latest Spring Boot 2.X versions here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter
Remember, only look for version 2.X if you need to use Java 8.

If you have used Spring Initializr, you will need to change **at least** following lines in your `pom.xml`:

1. Spring Boot version

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.18</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

2. Java version:

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

You might also need to adjust some other library versions, particularly if you chose Spring Cloud in Spring Initializr. Usually, Spring Boot will notify you of these problems when you start the application. If you're unsure about your tech stack or face other issues, feel free to ask in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the Springboot initializr from [aliyun](http://start.aliyun.com)?

or manually modify the version in it after using the initializr